# Run a forever loop with asyncio gather instead of running it multiple times in a channel connection main loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm writing a program that will send multiple data points between the sender and the receiver. These data points must be sent/received concurrently and frequently.
Here is the program that describes my idea:

```
async def send(dataPoint): 
  # Do sending action
  asyncio.sleep(samplingRate)

async def doTasks():
  tasks = [ send(dataPoint) for dataPoint in dataList ] 
  await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while channel_connection.ok():

        asyncio.run( doTasks())
```

By using asyncio gather, the program can run sending actions concurrently.  When all sending tasks of asyncio gather finish, because it's set in the channel_connection loop, it calls `asyncio.run( doTasks())` again. It repeats the gathering tasks action. I need the program to initiate only one gathering action and maintain it in the asyncio event loop. I find [`loop.run_forever()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) may solve the problem. However, I still feel confused about it. If we use `loop.run_forever()`, we have two main loops now: the `channel_connection.ok()` and the `asyncio` event loop. How will it affect to the
performance?
Is there anyways to handle this problem?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: why don't you move that logic from main function to separate function and run that

Comment: @deadshot, thanks for your reply. The reason why I have to set asyncio.run( doTasks() ) in the channel connection is to send the data points. In otherwords, we need the channel connection establish to send data. While channel_connection.ok() is to maintain the channel connection.

Comment: >I need the program to initiate only one gathering action. What do you mean? `gather` waits for all futures to complete (apart from exceptions)

Comment: Yeah, gather waits for all futures to complete. I mean I need to call asyncio.run( doTasks()) one time. Because asyncio.run( doTasks()) command is set in the channel connection loop. While it still true, it call  asyncio.run( doTasks()) multilpe times. Then the logic repeats again. 
I need the array of tasks are fixed and created one time instead of handling them multiple times asyncio.run( doTasks()) call doTasks function.